# Java.Lang.Object cannot be converted to type Com.Tridion.Meta.PageMeta

Tags: dd4t

We are using DD4T with MVC 4 ASP.net in our application. If i restart my IIS and hit the page below error is thrown on page. And if i refresh the page again, the error is not appearing and page is loading successfully.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```
[ArgumentException]: Object of type Java.Lang.Object cannot be converted to type Com.Tridion.Meta.PageMeta.
   at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Utilities.JavaConversion.ConvertCollection(Collection source, Type valueType, Type valueConversionType)
   at DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionPageProvider.GetLastPublishedDateByUrl(String url)
   at DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.GetLastPublishedDateByUrl(String url)
   at DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.GetLastPublishedDateCallBack(String key, Object cachedItem)
   at DD4T.Factories.Caching.LastPublishDateChangeMonitor..ctor(String key, Object cachedItem, GetLastPublishDate getLastPublishDateCallBack)
   at DD4T.Factories.Caching.DefaultCacheAgent.FindCacheItemPolicy(String key, Object item, String region, List1 dependOnItems)
   at DD4T.Factories.Caching.DefaultCacheAgent.Store(String key, String region, Object item)
   at DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.TryFindPageContent(String url, String& pageContent)
   at TestWebApplication.Controllers.TridionPageController.Page(String pageUrl)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary 2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary 2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Which version of Tridion are you using?

Comment: @user678 - Did you manage to find a solution to this problem?  If so, could you please accept an answer or 'self answer'?  If you have not managed to solve it yet, can you add more details to the question please?

Comment: what Tridion and what Java version are you using? And are you using 64 or 32 bit?

Answer (score 5):

This looks very similar to some errors you might see when the wrong Juggernet files are deployed to your web application. I suggest you check that you have followed the installation guide as closely as possible.

As this is a DD4T installation, of course, you will also need to check that you have followed the relevant guidance from the DD4T project.

Typically - problems like this arise if you fail to deploy all the files correctly - perhaps the version you have used is for the wrong word length (32 bit vs 64 bit) or you have deployed files from the wrong Tridion version, or failed to deploy files that are required.

The type conversions that Juggernet does from Java types to .NET types are great when they work, but when they don't you get this kind of message.